# ESP32 WiFi connectivity issue with Iphone13 hotspot

Tags: iphone, wifi, esp32

I am trying to connect my ESP32-s3-devkit-1U to my Iphone13 hotspot but I am not able. I tested the WiFi connectivity capability of my ESP32 with an android phone and it works but I would like to connect to my Iphone hotspot.

I have read online that the Iphone13 supports 5GHz bandwidth and to configure the 2.4GHz supported by the ESP32 i have to enable the "maximaze compatibility" option on my Iphone hotspot setup page. Moreover, online they say to keep the Iphone unlocked while connecting because otherwise it would stop forwarding the SSID. Nevertheless, even following these guidelines the ESP32 is not able to connect.

I am using WiFi.h library from Arduino. I have checked, doing a scan of the seen network from the ESP32, that my hotspot SSID is visible but when I try to connect and check the WiFi.status() it returns "WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL" and I am sure that I have wrote the correct SSID and PASSWORD in the WiFi.begin().

Do you have any guess on what I could do to establish a connection between the ESP32 and my Iphone13 hotspot?

Thank you in advance :) .

Kind regards,
Edoardo